# Want to pass double quote as argument

Tags: escaping, parameter-passing, expect, double-quotes

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set arguments [lrange $argv 2 end]
expect "hello"
send "$arguments\r\n"
```

Trying to pass double quotes as arguments to script. Above is not working as expected.

How I am calling the script is

```
./ExpectScript.sh \" 1 \" 2 3 4
```

Output is

```
hello
{"} 2 3 4
```

Expected output is

```
hello
" 2 3 4
```

Comment: Double quotes are special to `Tcl`. Try using single quote and escape it. `./ExpectScript.sh \'1\' 2 3 4`

Comment: Thanks for answer. It returned: 3 4. My expectation is to see the double quota in the output, like: " 2 3 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lrange` return list. And you print list. If you want string, you can use `join`.

```
set arguments [join [lrange $argv 2 end]]
```